# Show image on jsp with spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a BLOB type image in mysql database and I want to show the image on the jsp. I am using Hibernate and Spring MVC. This is my Model class:

```
@Repository
@Entity
@Table(name = "foto")
public class Image {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_users", nullable = false)
    private Users user;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_foto")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id_foto;

    @Column(name = "tipo")
    private String tipo;

    @Column(name = "size")
    private String size;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "image")
    private byte[] image;

    //Getters and Setters
```

this is my controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("UserSession")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "loginUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loginUsers(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("username") String username,
            @RequestParam("password") String password) {

        Users user = usersService.loginUsers(username, password);

        if( user == null ) {
            ModelAndView MV = new ModelAndView("login");
            MV.addObject("erroreLogin", "username e/o password errati");
            return MV;
        } else if ( user.getAmministratore() == false ){
            request.getSession().setAttribute("UserSession",user);
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("homeUtente");
            mav.addObject("galleria", usersService.getAllFoto());
            return mav;
        } else {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("UserSession",user);
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("utenti");
            mav.addObject("lista", usersService.getAllUtenti());
            return mav;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.getSession().invalidate(); //invalido i dati presenti in sessione
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }

}
```

and in my jsp I use this for show my image from Image List because each user have a gallery to display:

```
<img alt="Kangoo_image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${galleria.image}" />
```

when i'm trying to display it in my jsp.It is showing something binary like [B@59e73b47. how can i display the image here in jsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the image on JSP without storing to filesystem and linking to it, you'll have to do a Base64 encoding of the byte array. Easily done by following lines

```
byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(usersService.getAllFoto());
String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
mav.addObject("galleria", usersService.getAllFoto());
```

Both IOUtils and Base64 are from org.apache.commonsEndFragment

Answer (score 0):

this appends beacause galleria.image returns a byte[] type, and on the resulting html of the jsp appear the byte[].toString() value. exactly [B@59e73b47.

you should use something like:

```
<img alt="Kangoo_image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,new String(${galleria.image})" />
```

or

```
<img alt="Kangoo_image" src="/getImage/${galleria.id_foto}" />
```

and in in the **getImage** controller somthing like this

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

@RequestMapping("/getImage/*")
public void getImage(ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {

    requestUri = requestUri.substring((request.getContextPath() + "/getImage/")
            .length());

    Image image = DAO.findById(requestUri);

    String requestUri = request.getRequestURI();

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getImage());
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    String name = image.getName() + ".jpeg";
    String attachment = "inline; filename=" + name;
    response.setHeader("content-Disposition", attachment);
    response.setContentLength((int) baos.toByteArray().length);
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
    is.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Controller
 @SessionAttributes("UserSession")
 public class LoginController {

 @Autowired
 private UsersService usersService;

 @RequestMapping(value = "loginUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView loginUsers(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("username")   String username,
        @RequestParam("password") String password) {

    Users user = usersService.loginUsers(username, password);

    if( user == null ) {
        ModelAndView MV = new ModelAndView("login");
        MV.addObject("erroreLogin", "username e/o password errati");
        return MV;
    } else if ( user.getAmministratore() == false ){
        request.getSession().setAttribute("UserSession",user);
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("homeUtente");
         byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encode(usersService.getAllFoto());
         String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
          mav.addObject("userImage", base64Encoded )
        return mav;
    } else {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("UserSession",user);
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("utenti");
        mav.addObject("lista", usersService.getAllUtenti());
        return mav;
    }
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.getSession().invalidate(); //invalido i dati presenti in sessione
    return new ModelAndView("login");
 }

}
```

and in jsp code use this code to display image

```
     <img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${userImage}" />
```